# Powershell error "you cannot call a method on a null-valued expression"

Tags: powershell

I need to find the problem in this script
when I executed I got this message in the log

> you cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

```
for( $i = 0; $i -lt $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Count; $i++)

 {

try{

      $valuestr = New-Object -TypeName System.Text.StringBuilder

      for ( $x = 0; $x -le 10; $x++)

      {
       if ($x -lt 10)
        {
         [void]$valuestr.Append("' " +$DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[$i][$x].ToString().Trim().Replace("'","/")+"',")

         }
          else
          {

           [void]$valuestr.Append("' " + $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[$i][$x].ToString().Trim().Replace("'", "/")+"'")
           }
         }

         $sqlCmdd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO $sqlTable (ICN,ICN_CREATE_DT,ICN_SEQ_NUM,ICN_SUBNUM,USR_REF,USR_REL_REF,MSG_TYP,SW2_SLA_111,SW2_UETR_121,MT097_165) Values (" + $valuestr.ToString() +  ")"

        $sqlCmdd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    }
catch
{
 
$_.Exception.Message | Out-File C:\musta\logError.txt -Append

        }  
}
```

I executed and the error was displayed:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.

At line:13 char:103

[void]$valuestr.Append("' " + $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows[$i][$x].ToString <<<< ().Replace("'", "/")+"'")

CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (ToString:String) [], RuntimeException

FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: Which statement triggered the log message?

Comment: The inner loop iterates 11 times but you only have 10 columns. Change `$x -le 10` to `$x -lt 10` in the loop condition, then change `if($x -lt 10)` to `if($x -lt 9)`

Answer (score -1):

Big Thank for your help Bro Mathias R. Jessen the issue solved.

The inner loop iterates 11 times but you only have 10 columns. Change $x -le 10 to $x -lt 10 in the loop condition, then change if($x -lt 10) to if($x -lt 9) –
Mathias R. Jessen

Comment: Fair enough - if you think others may benefit, you should keep the question around. Thanks for adding the solution to the answer.